# SPARQL query RDFS ontology

Tags: sparql, ontology, rdfs

I have an RDFS ontology where i have one class Person and another class Department
The class Person has a property called has_name and a property called member_of with domain 
Person and range Department.
The class Department has a property called dep_city and another called dep_name,both have domain Department and range literal.

I want to create a query so that returns the has_name value of every Person that is member_of a Department that has dep_city = "New York".

My question is how to connect the two classes that i need to create my query.

I can return the dep_name of all the Departments that have dep_city = "New York"

I also know how return all the has_name of all the Persons but i don't if i can connect the two.

Please help me
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what namespace you use, so I will use `http://example.org/`

```
SELECT ?name
WHERE {
    ?person <http://example.org/has_name> ?name .
    ?person <http://example.org/member_of> ?department .
    ?department <http://example.org/dep_city> "New York"
}
```

By the way, have you read [SPARQL 1.1 Query](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) specification? It is a very concise document with a lot of examples